# In Pylint, can I override global message control based on filename?

Tags: python, pylint, pylintrc

I use a `pylintrc` file to disable some pylint warnings project-wide, but I'd like to disable some more messages just for files named `SConscript`.

Currently, I have a `# pylint: disable=...` in the beginning of each `SConscript` file, but it's a pain to maintain.

Is there a way to tell pylint to have extra suppressions based on the processed filename? (or regex, or whatever)

Answer (score -1):

Solution to setup in your `pylintrc` config file this setting:

```
# Add files or directories matching the regex patterns to the blacklist. The
# regex matches against base names, not paths.
# Ignore all .py files under the 3rdparty subdirectory.
ignore-patterns=SConscript,**/3rdparty/**/*.py,.venv
```

With this setting pylint scan will ignore the filename/directory/packagename patterns you setup here.

Comment: The question was about disabling "*based on the filename*". The OP already has `pylint: disable` at the beginning of the target files, but "*it's a pain to maintain*".

Comment: Thank you, now i see this. I will edit my answer to a proper now. Update: finished!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This seems to work well for ignoring a file entirely. What I was looking for is ignoring based on a combination of file pattern and rule pattern (e.g. "ignore  all `undefined-variable` errors in files that match pattern `SConscript`")